# Can a Jawa, Tusken Raider, or Hutt produce Force-sensitive offspring?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

Curious if there's anywhere you've heard of that says they absolutely cannot. If they can have Force-sensitive children, I was going to write a little piece of fiction on a Tusken Raider, Jawa , or Hutt becoming a Jedi Padawan- but before I did so, I wanted to make sure I was staying as close to Lucas' Universe as possible. I thought it'd be clever if a member of one of the most recognized, yet despised, races of the Galaxy reached such an honorary rank.

Comment: Hutt Jedi exists in Legends who was killed by Leia after he fell to the dark side.

Comment: With each other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Disney Canon

Unknown.

### EU/Legends:

- **Hutt** - evidently, very rare. But there was one Hutt Jedi: [Beldorion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beldorion). It [didn't end well](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beldorion#Biography).
- **Jawa** - There was one Jawa Jedi as well. [Akial](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Akial). And some EU canon hinted that there existed [female Jawa shamans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jawa/Legends#cite_note-Databank-0) who were Force-Sensitive.
- Tuskens: Never saw a mention of a Force-Sensitive one. A'Sharad Hett if frequently mistaken for one, but he's 100% human genetically, contrary to frequent perception, not half-Tusken.

### Bonus EU/Legends Round

- [Tree-like species Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tricky_Trap_Tree)
- [blue goofy elephant Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nem_Bees)
- [Ewok Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Ewok_Jedi). Yub Yub.
- [Stegosaus Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thon)
- [Wampa Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ku-Kak)
- [Star Dragons. Literally. 1/3 of them were Force-sensitive](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Duinuogwuin)
- [A whole species of Force-sensitive <strike>sparkling</strike> **vampires**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anzat_%28species%29)
- [Living silicone crystals](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shard) ([who wore robotic exoskeletons](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ilum_%28Jedi%29))
- [Obi-Wan Kenobi's **Pet Rock**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/River_stone). Not kidding. Literally.
- And last, but by no means, [Skippy the Jedi Droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid)

### Wookieepedia summary

Not directly referenced, but each species is a Wikia link and some of them are properly cited

> Species with high number of Force-sensitives included Humans, Kel Dors, Ithorians, Twi'leks, Zabraks, Yoda's species, Nautolans, and even the rare and mysterious Duinuogwuins. Species producing low numbers of Force-sensitives included the Wookiees, Jawas, Hutts and Caamasi. The Neti, Anzat, Korunnai (a Human tribe), Vahla, Red Sith, Miraluka, and many other species were entirely composed of Force-sensitives. Gotals may all have possessed the ability to sense the Force, although they had little practical use for it. Jungle Felucians, as a species, were all Force-sensitive, but none were known to have become Jedi.
>
> Creatures such as the vornskr and ysalamiri of the planet Myrkr were other examples of non-sentient creatures who were considered Force-sensitive. An ancient mynock species was even rumored to have established a Force-sensitive run civilization relying on dark side energy.

Comment: Interesting! Is it suggested that Beldorion fell easily to the Dark Side because he was a Hutt? Or am I guilty of cultural stereotyping?

Comment: @ThruGog You probably are in this case, but don't worry about it, being a Hutt, he would be guilty of the same thing! (or was that cultural stereotyping by me now?)

Comment: @BMWurm - Oh you definitely are! Shame on you

Comment: The "Stegosau[ru?]s Jedi" looks more like a something-ceratops to me, maybe with a little bit of Ankylosaurus thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually one force sensitive tusken raider named KkH'Oar'Rrhr or hoar for short

Comment: You might wish to note that this character exists wholly within the Extended Universe (now referred to as "Legends") and as such, isn't part of the official Star Wars canon; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/KkH%27Oar%27Rrhr

Comment: Additionally, some more information about the character would be really beneficial.